# Arrays, Lists and Hashtables in Common Lisp

Tags: arrays, list, common-lisp, big-o, sbcl

I am wondering what is the difference between arrays, lists and hashtables in Common Lisp. That is, I am aware how to implement and use them syntactically. I am also aware of the computer scientific theory surrounding the three data types.

What I am wondering about is what is the Common-Lisp-particular implementation? How should one use them to optimize code for performance (both space and time)? Are there any idiosyncrasies when it comes to these data structures in Common Lisp? How expensive are they at run-time?

Answer (score 9):

The difference is the actual implementation and the performance (defined in terms of `O(size)`) that follows from the implementation.

### [Lists](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/14_ab.htm)

Lists are implemented as linked lists, so they can have complex nesting and data sharing.

1. Add to the beginning - `O(1)` ([`push`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_push.htm))
2. Add to end - `O(n)` ([`append`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm))
3. Random access - `O(n)` ([`nth`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nth.htm))

Since Lisp uses [`cons`-based trees](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/14_aa.htm)
to represent its code, one can expect linked lists to be relatively fast
(i.e., the constants in the `O(n)` above should be small).

### [Arrays](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/15_.htm)

Arrays are implemented as vectors (contiguous sections of memory) with [multi-dimensional arrays](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/15_aacb.htm) on top of [vectors](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/15_aaca.htm) (index arithmetic is done automatically).
Arrays can also [share storage](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ar_dis.htm).

1. Add to the beginning - `O(n)` (need a loop to move over the data)
2. Add to end - `O(1)` ([`vector-push-extend`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_vec_ps.htm)) - on average, if you use [fill-pointer](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/15_aacaa.htm) &c.
3. Random access - `O(1)` ([`aref`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_aref.htm))

If you use [specialized arrays](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/15_ab.htm) to
avoid boxing, you should be aware that the data may be boxed on access.
E.g., if `v` has type `(simple-array double-float (5))`, then `(aref v 2)` may have to allocate memory to box the return value (the compiler
*may* eliminate some of such allocations, but you need to be aware of
the peril).

### [Hash Tables](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/18_.htm)

Hash tables are completely different - they are *not* [sequences](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/17_.htm), so they allow mapping from arbitrary data (as opposed to integer indexes for sequences), and access (both read and write) is `O(1)`.

Hash tables can be compared to [association lists](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/14_aba.htm) and [property lists](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_p.htm#property_list) (which can be an excellent alternative for tiny tables).

The major considerations for hash tables are

1. The correct choice of the test function
2. The quality of the hash function
3. The impact of garbage collection

E.g., many implementations will hash all
[`standard-class`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_std_cl.htm) instances to
the same bucket, making your hash table perform as a *list*.

If you use an `eq` hash table, an implementation may use object address
in memory as the (source of the) hash, and if it has a copying garbage
collector, it will have to re-hash all hash tables on each GC.

You might find it best to use strings as hash table keys, as they are
usually hashed best.
This is because [packages](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_.htm) are,
essentially, glorified string hash tables hooked into the
[reader](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/23_.htm), so implementations are
usually make sure that they are very good.

Comment: He said ' I am aware how to implement and use them syntactically. I am also aware of the computer scientific theory surrounding the three data types.' I thought this covers your answers so far...

Comment: @RainerJoswig: I expanded my answer to clarify lisp-specific issues.